# Arch Linux install doesn't boot

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, boot-loader

I've got Arch Linux mostly installed, and I seem to have installed GRUB with no problem. My partition table looks like this:

```
                              cgdisk 0.8.7
                          Disk Drive: /dev/sda
                       Size: 625142448, 298.1 GiB

Part. #     Size        Partition Type              Partition Name
------------------------------------------------------------------
            1007.0 KiB  free space
   1        15.0 GiB    Linux filesystem            root
   2        1007.0 KiB  BIOS boot partition         bios
            17.0 KiB    free space
   3        283.1 GiB   Linux filesystem            home
```

After partitioning my drive like this, I ran:

```
root@archiso ~ # arch-chroot /mnt /bin/zsh
root@archiso [02:19:45] [/]
-> # grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck /dev/sda
Installation finished. No error reported.
```

However, when I boot, I get

```
GRUB _
```

The underscore blinks, but I can't type anything. I still have access to the Arch installation by using the original install disk and `chroot`ing into it, but obviously I don't want to do this every time I start up my laptop. What could possibly be preventing me from booting properly? I've made sure my partitions conform to what [the GRUB page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Grub2#GUID_Partition_Table_.28GPT.29_specific_instructions) says I need, but to no avail.

For reference, I'm using the [Arch Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide) and I've chronicled the epic story of how I spent my Saturday on [my wiki](http://thoughts.muller.io/doku.php?id=arch-linux).

Comment: I've never needed to specify --target for grub-install. Does it by any chance work better if you don't? Also, it seems a weird failure case for something like that, but I'd double-check /boot/grub/menu.lst to make sure it isn't broken, and maybe try using a GRUB device specifier such as `(hd0)` rather than `/dev/sda`.

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly without `--target`. I did end up using `/dev/sda` to specify the device. After these changes, and an overdue adjustment to my `fstab`, it booted to a login shell. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice that you are specifying the CPU architecture using the `--target` parameter to grub-install. This would normally not be needed, as you'd want to use the same architecture GRUB as your running system is using.

Unless you have some specific need like "cross-compiling" a boot device for a different architecture, you shouldn't need to specify --target at all.

It may also be worth using a GRUB device identifier rather than a Linux device node name to identify the place whereto install the boot loader. In your case, that would *probably* be `(hd0)` rather than `/dev/sda`.